# Reading columns from a CSV file doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, lda

I have a `.csv` dataset of news articles which (should have) columns of publication, date, title etc. When I open this file with Numbers it perfectly shows this, every column is accounted for. However, when I try to use the file in the `Jupyter` Notebook, the columns don't seem to work properly. Here is what I have:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table("filename.csv",encoding="utf-8")

data.columns #and
```

then it gives me:

```
Index(['SEARCH_ROW,PUBLICATION,DATE,TITLE,EDITION,BYLINE,LANGUAGE,SECTION,JOURNAL-CODE,NYT,PUBLICATION-TYPE,LENGTH,LOAD-DATE,TEXT'], dtype='object')
```

Opening the file with Microsoft Excel gives me the same problem; every column is named:

```
SEARCH_ROW,PUBLICATION,DATE,TITLE,EDITION,BYLINE,LANGUAGE,SECTION,JOURNAL-CODE,NYT,PUBLICATION-TYPE,LENGTH,LOAD-DATE,TEXT
```

Is there someway to split this one-big column in to the original multiple columns form?

Comment: either use `sep=','` or `pd.read_csv()`, which uses comma as a sparator per default

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pd.read_table(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) uses `tab` (`'\t'`) as a separator per default.

So try to specify comma as a separator explicitly:

```
pd.read_table(filename, sep=',')
```

or use [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which uses comma as a sparator per default

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
data = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',')
```